# How do I rotate a target object around axis A by how much a different object is rotated around axis B?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a steering wheel that I want to rotate in Y axis.

By rotating this wheel I want to rotate a mirror and this mirror to follow the rotation of steering wheel, but in Z axis and not in Y axis.
Can someone please help me ?

I tried this one but it is rotating the 2 objects in same axis

```
void Update()
{
    mirror.transform.localRotation = stairing.transform.localRotation;
}
```

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can get the steering wheel's `y` rotation with [`Quaternion.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) and getting the `y` component:

```
float rotateAngle = stairing.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
```

You can set the mirror's `localRotation` to only rotate by `rotateAngle` around the Z axis by calling [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) with a forward vector whose length is the angle you'd like to rotate:

```
mirror.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * rotateAngle);
```

In your case, combining them might look like this:

```
void Update()
{
    float rotateAngle = stairing.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
    mirror.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * rotateAngle );    
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)